# High p-value but confidence interval that excludes 0?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, p-value, hypothesis-test, significance

In an A/B test, I'm calculating the proportion of Group A that have done something and comparing to the proportion of Group B that have done something to see if there is a meaningful difference. I run a t-test and find that the difference of -30% has a p-value of ~0.99, so I fail to reject the hypothesis that these proportions are different.

I want to show the 95% confidence interval around that difference and it's [-0.6238, 0.0084]. That's so close to not straddling 0, so I run a 90% confidence interval and it's [-0.5730, -0.0424].

How is it possible for the p value to be so high but the 90% confidence interval excludes 0?

Comment: the p-value looks wrong.  can you include the code to calculate it ? otherwise it's pretty much hand-waving about what went wrong

Comment: @StupidWolf ... that is because it was incorrect. I was feeding statsmodels proportions_ztest function the proportion of successes instead of the number of successes. Thank you for prompting me to look under my nose!